# Gnuplot: how to print greek letters from a data file?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to draw a simple linespoints with x-axis marked as greek letters instead of integers. The sample data file looks like the following:

\alpha   2.0

\alpha+1 3.0

\alpha+2 2.5

instead of

0 2.0

1 3.0

2 2.5

how to render the greek letters?
Thanks

Harryy

Answer (score 0):

The `\alpha` notation reminds me of [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). You might use some LaTeX related tool (e.g. `pdflatex`).

However, the Greek alpha is present in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), as `α` U+03B1 GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA. If you just want that, be sure to use [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) and encode it appropriately (e.g. as `\316\261` in a C UTF-8 encoded string)

I guess that recent versions of gnuplot could print Unicode letters. See [this example](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/enhanced_utf8.html).

So change your data file to contain UTF-8 alphas, or transform it appropriately with [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html).